# Trigger an event-handler only after 2 specific, consecutive FileSystemWatcher events are raised

Tags: c#, .net, events

I'm working with some save data for a video game. The purpose is to copy the save to a backup location each time the save is updated. The updates happen in this order:

1. Delete existing Save
2. Create Temp File for Save and rename to name of original save
3. Populate Save file with data

I can capture the save by name on a timer, but an event driven backup solves a number of issues (locking files from the game and from my app, duplicate backups)

The question:

How can I kick off my backup event on the FileSystemWatcher CHANGE event that happens immediately after the FileSystemWatcher RENAME event?

My best guess would be to:

1. Create FileSystemWatcher to look for RENAME events
2. Setup event handler for those RENAME events
3. Inside the RENAME event handler, create another Watcher to catch CHANGE events
4. Setup event handler for those CHANGE events that then does the backup

I ran into issues with just looking at the CHANGE event as that was also looking at the DELETED and RENAME events, and had some issues with copying the file before it had been fully populated, causing corrupted backups.

Comment: Do you own the process that does the save? Why not just change it to do the backup instead of using `FileSystemWatcher`?

Comment: @NightOwl888 No, I don't. The process can create corrupted saves at times, which is where the need for a backup comes from. The issue has been present for a few years, and hasn't been fixed so this is the next-best alternative.

Comment: I setup a process similar to this years ago. IIRC, the way it was done was to listen for the change event and then use a retry loop to keep trying to get a write lock on the file (`FileAccess.ReadWrite`) until the other process lets go of it. Once a `FileStream` is opened, you can use it to copy the contents to the backup file. Unless you have a specific reason to, there is no need to delete, you just need to overwrite the backup file.

Comment: That sounds like it will work for me. There are some changes, but checking for the write lock in that way is a good way of solving some of the issues. I'll try it out. Thank you for the advice.